# Please Merge My Both Accounts

Tags: support

Would you please merge my both accounts [one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11695/thierno-m-sow) and [two](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/12704/thierno-m-sow) or add them in a single profile? Thank you. Best

I have also a stack exchange [three](https://stackexchange.com/users/4231454/thierno-m-sow)

Comment: Who said they're both yours? For all we know you just copied the display name and public stats of the older account and want to get illegal access to it. That's why we have [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) in place.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you but the merging-accounts couldn't work in this case since the first account is created on mathematica and the recent one on crypto-meta. I need just to see the both accounts on each profile. Thank you

Comment: You still need to prove you own both accounts, using the procedure outlined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 3):

See this page in the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to see the steps to merge.

You have to edit your both accounts and then contact the SE team to let your accounts merge. Contact via https://stackoverflow.com/contact.

Comment: Thank you. But I can't expect a fast reply on sunday

Comment: @ThiernoM.SOW: There should be no hurry since you can use both accounts now. When they are merged later, you will have your rep and stuff joined.

Comment: Thanks my dear. I am listening